# PHP scandir causing extra files

Tags: php

Why is it when i use scandir using PHP i get extra values

```
$portID = $this->id;
$dir = '/home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/public/images/'.$portID;
$contents = scandir($dir);
```

Is there something i dont know about the function which produces more values than are actually in the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's nothing wrong with Pekka's answer; I'll just add a more declarative and mockable realization from [SPL](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/):

```
class DirectoryFilterDots extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    function __construct($path)
    {
        parent::__construct(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));
    }

    function accept()
    {
        return !$this->getInnerIterator()->isDot();
    }

    function key()
    {
        return $this->getInnerIterator()->getPathname();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

here's an alternative using opendir

```
$dir = "/your/path";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($d = opendir($dir)) {
           while (($file = readdir($d)) !== false) {
                if ( $file != "."  && $file != ".." ){
                    echo "filename: $file \n";
                    $files[]=$file;
                }
           }
        closedir($d);
    }
}
```

if you insist on using scandir(), then use a loop to go through the array of files returned by scandir(), and then remove those you don't want from the array

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment on *just somebody*'s answer so this will have to be in a separate answer. As of PHP 5.3 there is the [FilesystemIterator](http://php.net/filesystemiterator) which extends the DirectoryIterator and skips dot-files by default.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to get rid of the dots and unnecessary files or directories.

```
// remove unnecessary dots etc
$result = array_diff(scandir('/dir/to/scan/'), array('.', '..', '.DS_Store'));
print_r($result);
```

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While it's hard to tell without the actual output of scandir(), I guess you mean the additional `.` and `..` entries.

They show up in the examples in the [manual](http://de3.php.net/scandir) as well. You will have to filter them out manually.

`.` refers to the current directory
`..` refers to the parent directory.

This tradition comes from the Unix world, where exactly historically, I don't know. I guess it is because it allows you to quickly see the permissions for the current and parent directories on each call of `ls`.

Comment: is there a way excluding these?  Whilst still using scandir to get all the filenames in the folder?

Comment: yes, through programming: foreach (scandir($path) as $entry) { if (!in_array($entry, array('.', '..'))) $contents[] = $entry; }

Comment: I always found suprising that - given the usual plethora of flags that PHP function have - scandir has no options to ignore `.` and `..`

Comment: The . and the .. are used with chdir and other command line applications to allow for including the current directory or the parent director in the application results.  If you are in a directory and want to go to the parent, you would use chdir .. and this allows you to choose the parent directory.  Otherwise you would only be able to traverse down the tree.  So . and .. were added as special directory names to make the Unix commands that involve directories more uniform.  Otherwise you would need some kind of special cases.